# Naming of an oredered pair of rounds in a distribted algorithm

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, naming, definition

I have a distributed algorithm for mobile networks that divides time into rounds of equal duration. There are two types of rounds : collect and distribute which alternate.
In a collect round an entity collects some information and in the distribute round it distributes what it has collected in the previous collect round.
I would like to find a name for an ordered pair of collect-distribute rounds where the collect is before distribute.
I have: "phase", "stage" and "block", but I am not sure these names are good enough since a round can also be considered as a stage of the algorithm.

Comment: A. this is NOT about programming, but naming stuff actually is a difficult part of it. B. My vote is `phase`, that is comprised of two parts (collect and distribute).

Comment: There seems to be very little chance that this question can be answered objectively, unless you're implementing a published algorithm (in which case you should use the terminology the original authors used). That said, my vote is on `phase` too.

Comment: ...and if pressed for an explanation, I'd say it's the repetitive nature of the process that makes me think `phase` is more appropriate than `stage`, it reminds me of the phase of a wave rather than the stages of a rocket. (But you can find plenty of examples where the above logic doesn't work, for example two-phase commits.)